# How to get the results two tables and how to display one field value in heading

Tags: php, mysql, sql

residential_projects(table name)

```
id    City   Project_name

1      1     Residential Property 1
2      1     Residential Project 2
```

residential_units_details (table name)

```
id   residential_project_id  cityId  unitType  price
1            1                  1     1 BHK    50000
2            1                  1     2 BHK    100000
3            1                  1     3 BHK    150000
4            2                  1     4 BHK    43430
5            2                  1     5 BHK    53530
```

Result i need like this

```
Property name= Residential Property 1
1 BHK = 50000 (price)
2 BHK = 100000 (price)
3 BHK = 150000 (price)

Property name= Residential Project 2
4 BHK = 43430(price)
5 BHK = 53530 (price)
```

I wrote the query like this

```
$first_second_tables = "
SELECT d.unitType 
     , d.price 
     , p.Project_name 
  FROM residential_units_details d
  LEFT 
  JOIN residential_projects p
    ON d.residential_project_id = p.id 
 WHERE City = 1
 ";

     $sql=mysql_query($first_second_tables);
     while($res = mysql_fetch_assoc($sql)){
         echo "<pre>";
         var_dump($res);
         echo "</pre>";
     }
```

I am getting answer

```
array(3) {
["unitType"]=>
  string(1) "1"
  ["price"]=>
  string(5) "50000"
  ["Project_name"]=>
  string(22) "Residential Property 1"
}
array(3) {
  ["unitType"]=>
  string(1) "2"
  ["price"]=>
  string(6) "100000"
  ["Project_name"]=>
  string(22) "Residential Property 1"
}
array(3) {
  ["unitType"]=>
  string(1) "3"
  ["price"]=>
  string(6) "150000"
  ["Project_name"]=>
  string(22) "Residential Property 1"
}
array(3) {
  ["unitType"]=>
  string(1) "4"
  ["price"]=>
  string(5) "43430"
  ["Project_name"]=>
  string(21) "Residential Project 2"
}
array(3) {
  ["unitType"]=>
  string(1) "5"
  ["price"]=>
  string(5) "53530"
  ["Project_name"]=>
  string(21) "Residential Project 2"
}
```

I have two table, property name stored in one table (residential_projects), and property price and unit type stored in another table (residential_units_details). I have one property and same property I have different unit type (BHK), now I want to display the results like

> 1 BHK means what is the price and property name, and 2 BHK means what
>   is the price and property name

Here I am getting the correct answer but I am facing one problem property name also coming from loop. While display the front end property type in one heading and remaining details is loop

Comment: not understanding what you want to see in your output. Can you clarify?

Comment: in output [Project_name],coming from loop , for me don't want to loop because property name is same means i want display one time only how can do this

Comment: oh just render it before the loop $res[0]['Project_name']

Comment: can u please update your answer

Comment: Everytime you use PHP's deprecated mysql_ API a kitten somewhere dies. I'm fast running out of kittens.

Comment: Change `WHERE` to `AND` (or change `LEFT JOIN` to `JOIN`)

Comment: Can u please update your answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you only Want the Name to output if its a new name then you can run a test on each trip through the loop

```
     $first_second_tables = "SELECT residential_units_details.unitType , residential_units_details.price ,  residential_projects.Project_name FROM residential_units_details LEFT JOIN residential_projects ON residential_units_details.residential_project_id = residential_projects.id WHERE City = '1'";


     $sql=mysql_query($first_second_tables);
     $projectName = ''; //initialize our test variable


     while($res = mysql_fetch_assoc($sql)){
         // if the project name is different output it now
         if( $projectName != $res['Project_name'] ){
             echo $res['Project_name']   ;
         }else {
             // don't echo anything
         }
         echo "<pre>";
         var_dump($res);
         echo "</pre>";
         $projectName = $res[0]['Project_name'];
     }
```

Comment: Otherwise while running the while loop first time only i want print Project_name,it is possible ?

Comment: i modified the script try again

Comment: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ':', expecting ',' or ';' in

Comment: getting error again,can u please check it once and update me

Comment: i tried your code but condition is not taking properly i am geting like this Residential Property 1
Residential Property 1
Residential Property 1
Residential Project 2
Residential Project 2

Comment: but actual result should come like this  Residential Property 1 ,Residential Project 2

Comment: your code is working fine we have to declare variable $projectName = $res['Project_name']   ; then echo $projectName , remaining your code

Comment: Thanks,i got solution